# MvvmCross and view navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross for my application and starting with iPhone.  To achieve the sophistication on navigating between views using RequestNavigate and Close I've derived a new presenter from MvxBaseTouchViewPresenter.  So far so good.

The problem I'm having now is that it is possible to close or show a view while the previously visible view is still in transition, either opening or closing. The only way I could think of to work round this problem was to use the ViewDidAppear and ViewDidDisappear event handlers of view controllers to call an Action that does the showing of the next view thereby deferring the showing until after the previous view has finished its transition.

This means I have to add:

```
        public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);

        DoPostTransitionAction();
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);

        DoPostTransitionAction();
    }

    private void DoPostTransitionAction()
    {
        if( _postTransitionAction != null)_postTransitionAction();
    }

    private Action _postTransitionAction;

    public void ShowActionAfterTransition( Action postTransitionAction)
    {
        if( this.IsBeingDismissed || this.IsBeingPresented)
        {
            _postTransitionAction = postTransitionAction;
        }
        else
        {
            _postTransitionAction = null;
            postTransitionAction();
        }
    }
```

to view controllers, introduce an IEventViewController interface to make me add the code and change the Show method of the presenter to be:

```
    public override void Show(MvxShowViewModelRequest request)
    {
        // find the current top view as it will disappear as a result of
        // showing the requested view
        // note: this will be null for the first show request
        var topViewController = TopViewController;

        // if the request is to roll back an existing stack of views
        // then rollback to the bottom of the stack
        if (request.ClearTop && topViewController != null)
        {
            RollBackStack(topViewController);
        }

        // the top view is about to be 'covered' by the view requested
        // if the top view is transitioning (appearing or disappearing)
        // then wait for it to finish before showing the view requested
        var disappearingViewController = topViewController as IEventViewController;

        // if the top view is disappearing and it's of the 'event' type
        // delay calling Show until after the view has disappeared
        if( disappearingViewController != null)
        {
            // the top view has been requested to close and will fire the
            // 'transition complete' event when it has

            // register the action to perform when the top view has disappeared
            disappearingViewController.ShowActionAfterTransition (() =>
            {
                Show (CreateView(request), true);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // show the view now as the top view is either not closing
            // or, if it is, is not going to say when it does

            // create a view controller of the type requested
            Show(CreateView(request), true);
        }
    }
```

What I'd really like to have would be those event handlers in the base class.  I wonder what are the chances without me setting myself adrift from the main development path? Partial classes might do it?

Comment: Could you do this just in the presenter? e.g. by queueing the navigation requests and then hooking into your UINavigationController's delegate somehow - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007662

Comment: Another idea - you could implement some sort of messenger mechanism to let the ui (presenter) know that you want to do this 'special' action - then the presenter can do the action. (to do any more on this... I think I really need a more concrete use case about what the ux is - a more specific description of exactly what views you want to show/hide)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion Stuart.  Plenty to think about there.